# Add KVO to property of category for core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

As an example I have an NSManagedObject class that has two properties the I have a category that returns the results of the two properties. Bellow is some code to describe the problem. What I would like to do is allow other classes to add observers for this new property and be updated when this property has has changed. What I think I should do is have the class observe itself, however I am not sure where to add these observers.

```
@interface ClassA : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * number;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *classBs;
@end

@interface ClassB : NSManagedObject
@end

@interface ClassA (category)
@property(nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat result;
@end

@implementation ClassA (helper)
-(CGFloat) result{
    if (self.classBs.count == 0){
        return 0.0;
    }
    return (float) self.number.floatValue / (float)self.classBs.count;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Registering Dependent Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-BAJEAIEE), where you'll learn that you can provide a class method that follows the pattern `+(NSSet*)keyPathsForValuesAffecting<Key>`, like this:

```
+ (NSSet*) keyPathsForValuesAffectingResult
{
    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"number", @"classBs", nil];
}
```

If you add that method to your category, observers should be properly notified that `result` has changed whenever `number` or `classBs` changes.